# Python: Using win32com.client.dispatch to open workbook deactivates the workbook add-in

Tags: python, vba, excel

I am trying to run an Excel macro from Python.

I've used this piece of code:

```
import os
import win32com.client

filepath = r"myfilepath"

if os.path.exists(filepath):
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=filepath)
    xl.Application.Run("SendReport")
##    xl.Application.Save() # if you want to save then uncomment this line and change delete the ", ReadOnly=1" part from the open function.
    xl.Application.Quit() # Comment this out if your excel script closes
    del xl
```

The code works fine, but my workbook uses custom VBA functions from an add-in. When I open the workbook with this dispatch method the add-in is deactivated and the functions don't work anymore.

Is there any alternative way to open the workbook that will leave my add-in active?

Answer (score 0):

I use (below) and my VBA code + external connections are not deactivated

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
```